# xset led 3 not working on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: xset

update my ubuntu recent version 21.04, but now my external keyboard backlight is not working. Previously it was working using "xset led on" in terminal and it is working perfectly on Windows. I even reinstalled ubuntu, used "xset led on", "xset led 3" and even "xset led 1 to 32" but the problem is still there.

Original post in Spanish: https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1347855/1

Answer (score 0):

That's because Ubuntu 21.04 uses Wayland by default.
Log out from your account, and from the gear icon at right bottom, select Ubuntu on Xorg.